# Converter um numero inteiro em um float com casas decimais

Tags: java

Como posso fazer para transformar um número:

5 Em: 0,0005

10 em: 0,0010

Estou tentando desse jeito:

```
int numero = 5;
float numero2 = Math.abs(numero / 10000);
```

Porém está me retornando assim: 0,0

Comment: Só dividir por 1000, não?

Comment: Sim, como é o método mesmo?

Comment: Só dividir normalmente... `var/1000`

Comment: Ok, e como posso fazer com valores INT de uma coluna? Mesmo eu colocando double no método ele me retorna somente 0,0 sendo que o valor na coluna é 5

Comment: Forneça um [mcve] do seu código, senão você só vai obter palpites.

Comment: O problema é que você está declarando como Int e Integer não aceita números depois da vírgula, tente utilizar o tipo float

Comment: Pronto editei..

Comment: `Math.abs(numero / 10000f);`

Comment: Me retornou 5.0E-4

Comment: Este resultado está certo, isso é notação cientifica. `5.0E-4` é o mesmo que `5.0 * 10^-4`, que resulta no valor que você quer. Se quiser o numeral sem notação, precisa utilizar outro tipo de dado, como BigInteger.

Comment: Ok, e como ficaria com o BigInteger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa nada mais é que uma peculiaridade do Java. Quando você exibe um valor na tela, implicitamente é chamado o método `toString` do objeto. Na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString(float)) deste método há o comentário que quando a magnitude do valor é inferior a 10^-3 ou superior a 10^7 o valor será exibido com a notação científica. Isso [**provavelmente**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264635/5878) é para deixar sua representação mais legível a humanos, visto que não altera em nada a execução do código (o valor não muda).

Na documentação de [`System.out.println(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(float)) é dito que sua execução é uma chamada para `System.out.print(float)` seguida de uma `System.out.println()`. Por sua vez, o método [`System.out.print(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(float)) exibe o valor retornado por [`String.valueOf(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(float)), que retorna exatamente o valor retornado por `Float.toString`. Já na documentação do método `System.out.printf` há que o retorno será o mesmo que [`System.out.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), que exibe os valores conforme as regras definidas para o [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), onde `f` é o formato para um valor decimal, sem invocar o método `toString`.

Como o resultado da expressão é menor que 10^-3, ele é apresentado como notação científica, ficando `5.0E-4`, que é o equivalente para `0.0005`.

Caso você queira mesmo exibir o valor sem a notação científica, pode exibir o valor através do método `printf`, no lugar do `println`, definindo o formato `%f`:

```
float numero = 5;
float numero2 = numero / 10000;
System.out.printf("%f\n", numero2);  // 0.000500
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DarkturquoisePerkyBagworm)</sup>