# Por que tipos primitivos com ponto flutuante divididos ou multiplicados por determinados múltiplos de 10 são exibidos em notação científica?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, ponto-flutuante

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/264627/28595) podemos ver que o Java possui uma peculiaridade ao exibir o resultado em certos tipos de operações com tipos primitivos que possuem ponto flutuante, como divisão por múltiplos de 10, que pode ser visto no exemplo retirado da pergunta linkada, abaixo:

```
int num1 = 5;
float num2 = num1 / 10000f;
System.out.println(num2);
```

Como pode ser [visto aqui](https://ideone.com/NH32OI), o resultado é `5.0E-4` e não 0.0005.

Entendo que essa é uma notação científica, que significa `5.0 * 10^-4`, que leva ao mesmo valor, mas não entendi o motivo do Java fazer essa modificação na exibição.

Na resposta linkada, há um trecho retirado da documentação que diz:

> (...) quando a magnitude do valor é inferior a 10^-3 ou superior a 10^7 o valor será exibido com a notação científica.

Existe alguma convenção ou motivo oficial pra linguagem adotar esse tipo de exibição no caso mencionado na citação? Ou como é afirmado na resposta, é apenas por legibilidade?

> Obs.: esta característica não ocorre com tipos `int` e `long`, como pode ser [**visto aqui**](https://ideone.com/7h7UMx)

Comment: Eu inclino-me para legibilidade puramente. `0.0000000523` ou `100000000` são bem difíceis de ler e ter uma noção de grandeza ao passo que `5.23 × 10^-8` e `1 × 10^8` são bem mais fáceis.

Comment: Parece-me que isso é uma herança do [`printf("%g", f)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) do C. Nele, é especificado que vai ser assumida a representação mais curta entre o modelo absoluto e onde magnitude. E o ponto de virada é justamente `0.001`, que tem 4 caracteres, para `1e-3`, com quatro também. Portanto, o número decimal menor implicaria em necessitar ser descrito com a notação `e` para ser a menor string possível

Comment: Na documentação do `Float.toString` há este trecho: "*How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, **and beyond that as many, but only as many**, more digits as are needed to **uniquely distinguish** the argument value from adjacent values of type float.*" (adaptado); o que dá, de certa forma, suporte ao comentário do Jefferson sobre exibir sempre o mínimo de caracteres possível - no trecho é falado sobre o número de casas decimais, mas a ideia é a mesma: exibir o que importa sem introduzir ruídos.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Ainda assim há algo inconsistente nessa logica porque `100000.0` é escrito como `100000.0` ao invés de `1.0E5` que seria mais curto.

Comment: Talvez seja com o objetivo de economizar memória... https://dealunoparaaluno.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/os-8-tipo-de-dados-primitivos-em-java/

Answer (score 2):

É puramente arbitrário, cada linguagem tem seu critério, e visa evitar que um número muito grande ou muito pequeno gere uma string muito grande (imagine 10^300, que é 1 seguido de 300 zeros).

Agora, isto é o formatador default, que você nunca usa num programa "de verdade", a não ser para debugar. Na hora de mostrar o valor para o usuário você deve sempre usar um formatador específico, aí você assume a responsabilidade e.g. num programa de contabilidade você pode permitir a exibição de números muito grandes (até trilhões, talvez) mas sempre com 2 decimais fixas.

Answer (score 0):

Deve ser uma herança do projeto de linguagem do c++, onde um inteiro possui mesmo espaço ocupado em memoria que um float.

Comment: Eu gostaria de uma fonte oficial dessa informaçao, inclusive, eu citei isso na pergunta.

Comment: Nesse caso, recomendo o livro Conceitos de Linguagem de Programação, de Robert Sebesta. Vai sanar essa e várias outras dúvidas.